# »Dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen, haben ihr nicht viele zugetraut – das sei hier einfach zu teuer«

Tags: sentence-structure, subjunctive, expletiva

> Dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen, haben ihr nicht viele zugetraut – das sei hier einfach zu teuer.

If someone could help me please to understand the construction of this sentence. Specifically I have two points:

1. The main clause is: “haben ihr nicht viele zugetraut”. So why *haben*? Isn’t *es* the subject here?
2. “das sei hier einfach zu teuer” – should not *sei* be *wäre* here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen, haben ihr nicht viele zugetraut

"Dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen" is the object of the sentence (*Objektsatz*). The subject of the sentence is "Nicht viele", therefore it's "haben".

(To be more precise, "Dass es gelingen würde ..." is the direct [accusative] object and "ihr" is the indirect [dative] object. The terms *direct object* and *indirect object* are often problematic when talking about German sentences, but I think here it is appropriate)

Maybe this becomes clearer when the order of words is changed:

> Nicht viele haben ihr zugetraut, dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen.

-

> das sei hier einfach zu teuer

This can be seen as reported speech with an implied "Viele sagen, ...": "[Many people say that] this is too expensive here". For reported speech, *Konjunktiv I* is the ususal choice in written German, therefore "sei" is used. In spoken German *Konjunktiv I* is rare, here ususally *Konjunktiv II* ("wäre") is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the source of this sentence is this [Arbeitsbuch](https://books.google.de/books?id=wibSDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=Dass%20es%20gelingen%20w%C3%BCrde,%20in%20Deutschland%20konkurrenzf%C3%A4hige%20Textilien%20herzustellen,%20haben%20ihr%20nicht%20viele%20zugetraut%20%E2%80%93%20das%20sei%20hier%20einfach%20zu%20teuer&source=bl&ots=1wauwobC_t&sig=kocMjBJLZe9KLLz5w7cxT51JY74&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiozN6e-e_XAhUCXhoKHaRSB04Q6AEINjAB#v=onepage&q=Dass%20es%20gelingen%20w%C3%BCrde%2C%20in%20Deutschland%20konkurrenzf%C3%A4hige%20Textilien%20herzustellen%2C%20haben%20ihr%20nicht%20viele%20zugetraut%20%E2%80%93%20das%20sei%20hier%20einfach%20zu%20teuer&f=false), yes?

In German the easiest way to find out the sentence structure is to restructure the sentence, so let's do that:

**original**

Dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen, haben ihr nicht viele zugetraut – das sei hier einfach zu teuer.

**I**
Viele haben ihr nicht zugetraut, dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen – das sei hier einfach zu teuer

**II**
Viele haben ihr nicht zugetraut, dass es gelingen würde, in Deutschland konkurrenzfähige Textilien herzustellen, da das hier einfach zu teuer sei.

Viele haben ihr (das) nicht zugetraut

Subject - Viele - a lot of people

haben zugetraut - zutrauen - Perfekt

Object - das - specified in the Nebensatz

Your first question - haben:
haben zugetraut is Perfekt, vollendete Vergangenheit

Your second question - sei/wäre:
It is perfectly correct to write sei, it is "indirekten Rede", which asks for "Konjunktivs Präsens", and you will often find it in newspaper articles. It is similar to reported speech.

Comment: "haben zugetraut" is just Perfekt. Plusquamperfekt would be "hatten zugetraut".

Comment: You are right, corrected.